# How to get the hostname for a server with URL like http://www.europewebsite.co.uk?

Tags: java, url, webserver, httprequest, hostname

The project i am working on have multiple instances(i.e different website) running in single code base. Based on the URL we show corresponding website.

For example, if `http://www.uswebsite.com/` the we show US website. and if`http://www.cawebsite.com/`  will show Canadian website. The code that is written to detect this is

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

String server` = httpRequest.getServerName();
```

If request is from the `http://www.uswebsite.com/` then according to above code `String server = uswebsite` so we have additional code written to pop up the corresponding site

we  are now planning to include the European instance in the same code base and i see that the URL for the europe site is going to be  like this http://www.europewebsite.co.uk/. With getServer() as above will it fetch `String server=europewebsite`. By having the .co.uk at the end will the above code still get `String server=europewebsite` or `String server=europewebsite.co` Please advise as i can't test it out this in my local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording of your question is rather confusing, so I'm assuming that you simply want to extract the hostname from a hierarchical URL string.

The most reliable way to do it is to construct an instance of `java.net.URL` or `java.net.URI` for the url string, and use the relevant getter to extract the hostname.

---

On the other hand, if you are trying to detect the virtual hostname for the current request in a servlet, then your `httpRequest.getServerName()` gives you that hostname as it appears in the first line of the HTTP request (unless something has rewritten it ...).

---

On the other hand, if you simply want to extract `"europewebsite"` from a DNS name like `"www.europewebsite.co.uk"`, there is no general solution.  I'd recommend converting the DNS to all lowercase and doing a lookup in a table that you have pre-initialized with all of the variations that you are prepared to recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Normally httpRequest.getServerName() will return hostname, in your case it is complete name ie. "europewebsite.co.uk".